# Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget' on function call in html template

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this on my template: `<input type="file" id="upload" (change)="uploadImage($event.target?.files)" accept="image/*" hidden />` and it works just fine, but when I run `ionic build --prod` it gives me an error: `error TS2339: Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.`
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error `"Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'"` occurs when we try to access the files property on an element that has a type of `EventTarget`. To solve the error, use a type assertion to type the element as `HTMLInputElement` before accessing the property.

**html**

```
<input type="file" id="upload" (change)="uploadImage($event)" accept="image/*" hidden />
```

**ts**

```
interface HTMLInputEvent extends Event {
    target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
}

uploadImage(e?: HTMLInputEvent) {
    let files: any = e.target.files[0]; 
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is good but needs some modification under strict mode in Angular. The Input event will still be marked as an error.

Here's how I fixed it: The `uploadImage` function accepts a plain `Event` and converts it to the correct interface.

```
interface HTMLInputEvent extends Event {
    target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
}

uploadImage(e: Event) {
    const fileEvent = e as HTMLInputEvent;
    let files: any = fileEvent.target.files[0]; 
    //...
}
```